# How to create an integrated address with a payment id on Monero v12 GUI?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, integrated-address, sub-address

I don't see the option to create a new address using payment ids anymore on v12. Was this removed from the gui because of sub-addresses?

Comment: It does seem like it's missing in the gui, but if you're comfortable with the cli, the command `integrated_address` still works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The payment ids and integrated addresses are supposed to be phased out and replaced by subaddresses, which is why the integrated address generation was removed from monero-wallet-gui 0.12 and replaced by the subaddress generation.

For example, if you have some customers who have to pay you, instead of giving your main address and a payment id or an integrated address to each of them, you give a subaddress to each of them.